# Editing a selected card in angular

Tags: angular

hey guys i am trying to build an e commerce project so i m stuck at a point I am in my home component in which all my products are displayed in the form of Bootstrap Card.

Now what i want is on clicking the ADD TO CART button i want to render that specific card and update its ADD TO CART button as "1 ITEM IN CART "
To avoid confusion the Expected result is shown below in the link

https://ibb.co/F5yWSKY

and here is the card component

```
<div class=" row justify-content-md-center">
<div class="col-md-3 describe" *ngFor="let p of filteredproducts ;let 
i=index">
<mdb-card class="mdb">
<mdb-card-img src="{{p.imageurl}}" alt="Card image cap"></mdb-card-img>
<mdb-card-body>
  <mdb-card-title>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
  </mdb-card-title>
  <mdb-card-text> {{p.price}}
  </mdb-card-text>
 <div>


   <button class="button" id="btn" (click)="onclick(p,i)" mdbBtn 
type="button" color="primary" block="true" mdbWavesEffect>Add to 
Cart</button>

</div>
</mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
</div>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Productservice } from '../shared/product.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

allproducts:any[]=[]
category
filteredproducts:any[]=[]
selected
param1: string;
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router,private 
prservice:Productservice) {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.param1 = params['category'];

  this.allproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()


  this.filteredproducts=(this.param1)?
  this.allproducts.filter(p=>p.select===this.param1):this.allproducts
 }); 
 }

 ngOnInit() {
  // console.log(id)
 }

onclick(p,i){

  console.log(p,i)


}


}
```

Comment: Post your ts file too

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan updated !

Comment: which array represent your cart?

Answer (score 0):

It's too simple to implement.

```
<div class=" row justify-content-md-center">
<div class="col-md-3 describe" *ngFor="let p of filteredproducts ;let 
i=index">
<mdb-card class="mdb">
<mdb-card-img src="{{p.imageurl}}" alt="Card image cap"></mdb-card-img>
<mdb-card-body>
<mdb-card-title>
<h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
</mdb-card-title>
<mdb-card-text> {{p.price}}
</mdb-card-text>
<div>


  <button class="button" id="btn" (click)="onclick(p,i)" mdbBtn 
 type="button" color="primary" block="true" mdbWavesEffect>Add to 
Cart</button>

   /* customize as you want to show when a product added to cart.
    simply add two buttons plus and negative and in between of them add span 
   that will represent how much items are in the cart and use `*ngIf` to hide 
   and show when a product is in a cart or not respectively */

</div>
</mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the  real issue i m facing is that when i am rendering something it is geeting change to every card, i just only want changes in the card that i clicked not in all

Comment: match every product id to the cart contain product id and change that specific product.